# Android loading dots animation view

Tags: android, animation

I would like to create a loading indicator containing 3\4 dots.
the dots will be horizontally ordered, one after the other, and will appear sequentially until the lat dot, and then disappear and all over again.

is there an Android way to create it without using threads or dirty solution?
like animation, animation set \ list and etc.

link will be much appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Not an answer here but to help with your search you're after an indeterminant loading animation.

Comment: use an animation drawable: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html